# excel returns sheetname with $

Tags: excel, delphi

I read excel files using ADO and functions like below

```
procedure TForm1.ConnectToExcel;
var strConn :  widestring;
begin
  strConn:='Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;' +
           'Data Source=' + Edit1.Text + ';' +
           'Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;';

  AdoConnection1.Connected:=False;
  AdoConnection1.ConnectionString:=strConn;
  try
    AdoConnection1.Open;
    AdoConnection1.GetTableNames(ComboBox1.Items,True);
  except
    ShowMessage('Unable to connect to Excel, make sure the workbook ' + Edit1.Text + ' exist!');
    raise;
  end;
end;(*ConnectToExcel*)

procedure TForm1.FetchData;
begin
  StatusBar1.SimpleText:='';

  if not AdoConnection1.Connected then ConnectToExcel;

  AdoQuery1.Close;
  AdoQuery1.SQL.Text:='select * from' + SheetName;
  try
    AdoQuery1.Open;
  except
    ShowMessage('Unable to read data from Excel, make sure the query ' + SheetName + ' is meaningful!');
    raise;
  end;
end;
```

for several excel files this code worked quite well but now I try to open a new one with a strange error.

Inside the excel file the worksheet name is MYLIST,  if i retrieve the list of Worksheet names i get the name MYLIST$ back.  I can not open this worksheet even with MYLIST or MYLIST$. What might be the problem .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft Jet Engine does not allow "$" symbols in identifiers, only in built-in functions. If you use this symbol in your names, these identifiers should be quoted.
So try this:

```
select * from [MYLIST$]
```

Comment: this fixed my problem. Any idea why excel reports this $ at the end of the worksheetname ?

Comment: This is by-design behaviour of the Jet Engine. There are the following available "queryable" name types: `[Sheet Name$]` - entire sheet, `[Named Range]` - Excel "named ranges", `[Sheet Name$A1:F50]` - unnamed range